# Convert Html to PDF in laravel 5.2

Tags: html, laravel-5, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am working on a laravel 5.2 project. Here i want to convert some of my HTML pages into PDF files.
i was using dompdf library  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf but its not rendring bootstrap well. So now i am using laravelsnappy(https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) which is based on WKHTMLTOPDF webkit tool. its rendring all my css files in a desire way. but here is another problem that i am developing the project on my windows mechine and my hosting is on linux server and this tool giving me different results on different OS. i tried to set zoom level to fix its giving me a small font size on my server.
Can anyone pls tell me what should i do now . Or any other library which suits here.

Comment: you sould always try to mimic your hosting environment when developing. So think about using homestead or something to create a virtual machine of linux. Also try to stick to very standard html/css when generating html to pdf files since it doesn't like css3 and such.